# id field in django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework and just creating a simple serializer like this:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title','location')
```

However I get this error:

```
KeyError at /cerberus/packages/
'id'
```

How come I can't get the primary key 'id' as part of my serialized data? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`HyperlinkedModelSerializer` doesn't include the `id` by default.  In 2.2 and earlier you'll need to add it explicitly as a field...

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title','location')
```

From 2.3 onwards, you can simply add 'id' to the `fields` option...

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title','location')
```

From 3.x (< 3.3) onwards, you must use `ReadOnlyField()` instead of `Field()` if you want to add it explicitly and not use the `fields` option...

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Package
```

Comment: This tip helped me through a Tutorial of the rest_framework [link] (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization#using-modelserializers). In the tutorial there you have a line of `pk = serializers.Field()`, but it should be `id = serializers.Field()`. I oversaw that typo.

Comment: It should now be `id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()` for Django Rest Framework 3.x

Comment: Thanks..Good explanation!!

Comment: Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since version **3.3.0**. The third code example will therefore fail with an `AssertionError`.

Comment: And in the From "3.x (< 3.3)" Meta desc, what should be the fields: fields = ('id', 'url', 'title','location') or fields = '_ _all_ _' ??

Answer (score 18):

According to the [Django Rest Framework Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update):

> The default implicitly-generated id field is marked as read_only. This causes it to be removed on updates.

Thus, if you need the `id` field in an update method, you must not declare it as read-only but use a read-write field instead:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Comment: You should not have to declare the pk on the serialization model

Comment: @AlxVallejo you do if you want to be able to create an instance with a specific id rather than an auto id

Comment: I can't think of a circumstance in which you'd override the model's id with something else for serialization

Comment: Making a 64-bit id into a string to be valid Javascript, like Facebook does. (See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/). Base64 URL encoding an id, like Instagram probably does.

Answer (score 5):

I just tweaked this to make it a little more pluggable by creating this class:

```
class HyperlinkedModelSerializerWithId(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Extend the HyperlinkedModelSerializer to add IDs as well for the best of
    both worlds.
    """
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

Then, just use that to make your serializer and you're on your way.

Comment: Very Elegant. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

## Background

As of Django Rest Framework 3.14.0 (I'm using it right now), it would seem that none of the solutions provided above work. (Maybe romor's, but this response goes into much more details, IMO)

## Input

I have a BaseModel that has Meta property "abstract" set to True.
Then I'm creating a serializer for my non-base model.

Some sample code — Base Class:

```py
# _base.py
from uuid import uuid4

from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True...)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True...)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Model I'm making a serializer for:

```py
from django.db import models

from ._base import BaseModel


class Comment(BaseModel):
    file = models.FileField(...)
    text = models.TextField(...)

    author = models.ForeignKey("accounts.BaseUser"...)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Comment")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Comments")
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
```

As you can see, I have a field called `id`, an instance of UUIDField class.

Using a read-only field results in that `id` field being omitted from the response, even though it's present in the Model definition. I've tried this field as an option of UUIDField, and using ReadOnlyField directly.

## Solution

To fix this, I've created a serializer `ModelWithUUID`, it looks something like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class ModelWithUUID(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField()
```

So, in a way, this is what romor and Jann (the editor) suggested in their response.

By doing this, my final serializer is pretty simple, and looks like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(ModelWithUUID):
    author = AdditionalSerializerForAuthor()  # Not the actual name
    file = FileRepresentationField(allow_null=True)  # I need some "weird" conversions, don't judge me

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = "__all__"
```

This allows me to use `__all__` for fields and have an `id` field at all times.

*Additional background, that you may need to know to understand why I do things this way (you can skip this)*

> It should be noted that I use Django 5.0.1 and drf_yasg.
>
> Maybe my approach is wrong, but I use the serializer's `.data` property as data for response. And to be even more specific — I use a
> combination of 3 serializers for all (or almost all) of my endpoints:
>
> - Input Serialzier, that is used as a type hint for drf_yasg;
> - Output Serializer, same (CommentSerializer is a part of one);
> - Internal Seraializer, that takes data from Input Serializer, and returns an Output Serializer, or a Validation Error.
>
> This combination seems to be pretty flexible so far, but it may not be the best practice in the long run.