# How I can return id in ModelSerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use django rest framework ModelSerializer class. I need to return id of serializer model *LookupRequest*

```
class HistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vehicle = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

    def get_vehicle(self, obj):
        instance = models.Vehicle.objects.get(id=obj['vehicle'])
        return VehicleSerializer().to_representation(instance=instance)

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = models.LookupRequest
        fields = ['id', 'vehicle', ...]
```

But *id* value doesn't return in get request. Maybe someone know how i can return id. Thanks for any help.

Result that I have:

```
{"count":1,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":
    [{
        "vehicle":{...},
        "last_time":"2016-12-24T10:47:20.427Z",
        "has_changed":false
    }]
}
```

Comment: What's the sample output you are getting?

Comment: @EvansMurithi I've added an example in post.

Comment: can u post your `LookupRequest` definition

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit ReadOnlyField like in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014495/id-field-in-django-rest-framework-serializer ?

Comment: duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501622/5751147