# Don't understand Django REST Framework KeyError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working through the Django REST Framework v.2 [tutorial](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/tutorial/1-serialization) and am getting an error I don't understand.  The tutorial covers creating a simple pastebin code highlighting Web API.  You start by creating the following models and loading it with a few snippets:

```
# models.py
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                default='python',
                                max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                             default='friendly',
                             max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

# Python console
snippet = Snippet(code='foo = "bar"\n')
snippet.save()

snippet = Snippet(code='print "hello, world"\n')
snippet.save()
```

You then create a serializer class that serializes and de-serializes snippet instances into JSON:

```
# serializers.py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()  # Note: `Field` is an untyped read-only field.
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False,
                                  max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(widget=widgets.Textarea,
                                 max_length=100000)
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                       default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                    default='friendly')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance, given a dictionary
        of deserialized field values.

        Note that if we don't define this method, then deserializing
        data will simply return a dictionary of items.
        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
            instance.code = attrs.get('code', instance.code)
            instance.linenos = attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
            instance.language = attrs.get('language', instance.language)
            instance.style = attrs.get('style', instance.style)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Snippet(**attrs)
```

You also create two CBVs (I won't include them here, the code can be seen at the link above) that contains 'snippet_list' and 'snippet_detail' views that are called via these urlconfs:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail),
]
```

If you then execute these two curl commands, you get a list of snippets or details for a particular snippet:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/2/
```

These commands work just fine.  But the tutorial then goes on to replace the snippet class shown above with a simple ModelSerializer class:

```
# serializers.py
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

However, when I make this replacement and restart my server, I get this error:

```
KeyError at /snippets/
'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:
'id'
Exception Location: /Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in get_fields, line 257
Python Executable:  /Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.13

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.13
# ... Application and Middleware stuff

Traceback:
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/smith/code/django/drf2/snippets/views.py" in snippet_list
  29.         return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  581.                 self._data = [self.to_native(item) for item in obj]
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_native
  357.         for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  60.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in fields
  224.         return self.get_fields()
File "/Users/smith/.virtualenvs/django184/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in get_fields
  257.                 new[key] = ret[key]

Exception Type: KeyError at /snippets/
Exception Value: 'id'
```

Just to make sure I hadn't created a typo, I cut and pasted all the code from the tutorial into my Django files.  I also did an Internet search to see if anyone was having this problem.  In addition, I looked that the tutorial for version 3 of the framework and the module author uses this same ModelSerializer technique in version three.  Have I done something wrong?  Is there an error in the tutorial?

Comment: I guess you should replace id by pk in your variable fields, in meta.

Comment: Why are you following such an old tutorial? Django 1.8 is now end of life and does not receive security fixes any more. Even if you are unable to upgrade Django, you can still use rest framework 3.6.x with Django 1.8.x.

Comment: There may be a mismatch between the 2.x version of rest framework you are running and the 2.y version that the tutorial was written for.

Comment: I'm using v.2 because my production site is running Django 1.8.4 and I don't have time to upgrade it right now to a newer version that would be compatible with v.3.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014495/id-field-in-django-rest-framework-serializer) might help if you decide to stick with rest framework 2.

Comment: Try `url(r'^snippets/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail),` instead

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the help.  I didn't realize who you were and do appreciate the help.  The solution to the other question didn't work, but I'll see if DRF 3 will work per your suggestion.  And yes, I must carve out some time to update my Django.

Comment: I should add that the Django REST Framework page lists this requirement "Django (1.10, 1.11, 2.0)" which is another reason why I didn't use DRF3 at the start.

Comment: I want to confirm that DRF v.3 is *not* compatible with Django 1.8.x.  The routers.py module tries to import NoReverseMatch from django.urls.  This isn't possible with Django 1.8.x.

Comment: Have a look at the [release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#370). Support for Django 1.8 was dropped in version 3.7. The previous version 3.6.4 does support Django 1.8. The [3.6.4 page on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework/3.6.4/) also shows that it supports Django 1.8.