# How to add 'id' to the fields in HyperlinkedModelSerializer in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When using the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` from Django REST Framework, the field `id` is not included in the `fields` by default. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014495/id-field-in-django-rest-framework-serializer) has an answer that explains that well.

However I have a problem I'd like to solve in a particular way.

I have a model with custom ID and few dozens of other fields:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # 20-30 fields
```

In the `serializers.py` I'd like to include all fields from the model:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

However this doesn't include the field `id`. Defining `id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()` doesn't help me either, as `id` shoud be editable.

Specifying all the fields manually like this:

```
fields = ('id', # all other fields)
```

would be a solution I'm trying to circumvent because the model class has a lot of fields and they might change in future.

Is there an elegant possibility to add the field `id`? Maybe overriding the `__init__` method?

Comment: why don't you use `class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)`

Comment: @argo Because I need explicitly `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add **`id`** attribute in **`FooSerializer`** serializer as:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed elegant, simple and very straight forward.

Comment: **Simple is better than complex !!**

Comment: Unless you want to allow people to edit the `id` (which could lead to issues), I'd suggest adjusting the code to: `id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom HyperlinkedModelSerializer and override `get_default_field_names` to include the id like normal ModelSerializer does.

Example:

```
class CustomHyperlinkedModelSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer ):

    def get_default_field_names(self, declared_fields, model_info):

        return (
            [model_info.pk.name] +
            [self.url_field_name] +
            list(declared_fields) +
            list(model_info.fields) +
            list(model_info.forward_relations)
         )
```

Note : this is just an idea. I have not tested it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I managed to accomplish the task with overriding the `__init__` method and manipulate the fields. But neither that nor your proposal looks very elegant and is obfuscating.

Comment: This is exactly what we've done in a recent API project. The only change we made was moving the url field to the bottom of the list. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`HyperlinkedModelSerializer` doesn't include the `id` field by default. You can include `id` by adding it to the serializer as an attribute like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't add any value to the first answer from Jerin Peter George.